# Naming a function that loads on document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got a .js file that adds functionality to a menu when the page loads (when document is ready) ... the first three lines of the file are...

```
( function( $ ) {
$( document ).ready(function () {
$('#cssmenul li.has-sub>a').on('click', function(){
```

After that there's loads more code that adds colours and other visual effects.

At the moment the function doesn't have a name - it just runs.  However if I wanted to call the function from a button how do I name it?  If called the function activateMenu I would then have a button like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Activate" onclick="activateMenu();">
```

Thanks very much

Comment: you can create `activateMenu()` outside your anonymous `.ready()` function area ... and then reference it..

Comment: so get rid of the document ready and replace it with the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reuse the code as `activateMenu`, then you can group the contents of that code into its own function and reference it inside your `.ready()`

```js
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){
    activateMenu();
  });
})(jQuery);

function activateMenu(){
  console.log('test');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="activateMenu()">Test Button</button>
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you - I was barking up completely the wrong tree.  Solution is kind of obvious once it has been shown!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

create your function separately and the just pass the reference of it to the `ready` event, like this,

```js
function doSomething(){
  // do whatever you want to do
  console.log('doing something')
}

// then
$( document ).ready(doSomething)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="doSomething()">click me</button>
```